# MySql join 2 tables without single common field to exclude records

Tags: mysql

Using MySql and need to select (and later insert) data from temp_comments into comments - unless the comment exists in the comments table already. Here is some test data for an example

```
comments table
id | apn   | account   | comment
--------------------------------
1  | 100   |           | todays comment
2  | 101   |           | yesterdays comment
3  | 109   |           | todays comment
4  | 122   |           | more comments
5  |       | 34550     | todays comment
6  |       | 12433     | another comment


temp_comments table
id | apn   | account   | comment
-----------------------------------------
1  | 92    |           | todays comment
2  | 99    |           | another comment
3  | 100   |           | more comments
4  | 109   |           | todays comment
5  |       | 34588     | new comment
```

In this case, all except id#4 from temp_comments should be selected and inserted into comments (Because with that record, **apn | account | comment** all match a row in the comments table).

I tried getting a select statement working before trying the insert:

```
select apn, account, comment
from temp_comments
where not exists( select apn, account, comment
from temp_comments
except
select apn, account, comment
from comments)
```

Since EXCEPT doesn't work in mySQL, this pops an error. Not sure how to use a join instead since it all 3 fields need to match for me to want to exclude it. Once I get the SELECT working, I would need to insert into comments, such as:

```
INSERT into comments
apn, account, comments
SELECT (and put my working SELECT statement HERE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a `LEFT JOIN` to find all the rows in one table that don't have a match in the other table.

```
SELECT tc.apn, tc.account, c.comment
FROM temp_comments AS tc
LEFT JOIN comments AS c ON c.apn <=> tc.apn AND c.account <=> tc.account AND c.comment <=> tc.comment
WHERE c.id IS NULL
```

or with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT apn, account, comment
FROM temp_comments AS tc
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT *
     FROM comments AS c
     WHERE c.apn <=> tc.apn AND c.account <=> tc.account AND c.comment <=> tc.comment)
```

Comment: This is actually getting me results from comments, not temp_comments. Please note my edit - I did figure out how to pull data using CONCAT on all 3 fields.

Comment: Sorry, I just got them backwards.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer, not an edit to the question.

Comment: The `CONCAT` solution is not a good way to do it. If you have one row with `apn = 11, account = 20, comment = abc`, it will match another row with `apn = 1, account = 120, comment = abc`.

Comment: Excellent point - I've added an answer instead of a question and edited the CONCAT to prevent the issue you mentioned. Let me know if you think it might still give me the wrong info. Thx!

Comment: It will work, it's just a gross way to do it. It also can't make any use of indexes when comparing the columns.

Comment: Good point on index, but it's the only solution I've found so far that pulls what I need. I tried the NOT EXISTS but it pulls all 5 rows from TEMP not just the 4 I want - It doesn't filter out the row where apn, account and comment have an exact match in comments.

Comment: I see the problem, it's the `NULL` values, because `NULL = NULL` is not true. I changed to `<=>`, the [NULL-safe equality](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) operator.

Answer (score 0):

Per @Barmar's suggestion, I'm posting my answer instead of just leaving it as an edit in my original question. ALSO, @barmar made a good point on 11-20-Comment CONCAT the same as 1-120-Comment, so I made a edit to prevent that.

To do the select - just concat the fields and compare all 3 fields against the other. NOTE: Had to add the IFNULL to get proper results as apn or account is null if there is no value - wasn't clear in the table I listed. Here's the code I used for the SELECT:

```
select tc.apn, tc.account, tc.comment
from temp_comments tc
where 
concat("apn",IFNULL(tc.apn ,''),"acct",IFNULL(tc.account ,''),"comment",tc.comment) 
not in 
(SELECT concat("apn",IFNULL(c.apn ,''),"acct",IFNULL(c.account ,''),"comment",c.comment) 
from comments c)
```